# How to clone a branch with a forward slash in its name

Tags: git

I'm trying to clone a repository with a `/` in its name but I'm not sure how to clone it, as it would not let me. The repository I'm trying to clone is https://github.com/randombit/fecpp. The branch I'm trying to clone is `jack/cpuid` and the error that I'm getting when running

```sh
$ git clone -b jack/cpuid git@github.com:randombit/fecpp.git
```

is:

```
Cloning into 'fecpp'...
fatal: Remote branch jack/cupid not found in upstream origin
```

How do I clone this branch?

Comment: Got it: you typo'd in your question too: `branch jack/cupid not found`. "love"ly typo btw.

Comment: Yeah..I typed ```cupid``` instead of ```cpuid```...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[jthill@gadabout snips]$ git clone -b jack/cpuid git@github.com:randombit/fecpp.git
Cloning into 'fecpp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 492, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Total 492 (delta 8), reused 13 (delta 4), pack-reused 473
Receiving objects: 100% (492/492), 1.03 MiB | 2.07 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (283/283), done.
[jthill@gadabout snips]$ cd fecpp/
/home/jthill/src/snips/fecpp
[jthill@gadabout fecpp]$ git branch
* jack/cpuid
[jthill@gadabout fecpp]$
```

Works for me.

Comment: Oh wow, now I feel stupid, just checked the history of my command and I had a typo....

Comment: I personally have never once typoed a command and been unable to see it.

Comment: @jthill is it legitimate to vote to close and also answer and gain the acceptance tick? When I’ve done that, I get trounced.

Comment: @matt I voted to close after answering, I didn't see the typo at first.

Comment: Of course, but it still looks like a strategy of answering and then closing the door to other answers. It isn't forbidden but is it really something one wants to be seen to do? I'm just advising you that you can get the Meta folks on your case if you do that. It can get a bit painful. I speak from experience.